# Resetting StreamReader F#

Tags: .net, f#, streamreader

I have the following method which I use for downloading data from GET requests:

```
let fetchUrl callback url =      
    let req = WebRequest.Create(Uri(url)) 
    req.Method <- "GET"
    use resp = req.GetResponse() 
    use stream = resp.GetResponseStream() 
    use reader = new IO.StreamReader(stream) 
    callback reader url
```

Next I have a callback which uses the reader as follows:

```
 let myCallbackGetListings (reader:IO.StreamReader) url (chatMatch : ChatMatch) = 
    let html = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

This works fine the first time I use it, however the second time, it crashes on the line:

```
let html = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

with the exception:

```
Cannot read from a closed TextReader.
```

I tried doing:

```
reader.BaseStream.Position <- (0 |> int64)
reader.DiscardBufferedData()
```

however, this doesn't work either and throws the exception:

`Specified method is not supported.`

on the line attempting to reset the BaseStream Position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not always possible to set position of a stream. In this particular case, your stream comes from the network, and once you read it in, there is no way to "repeat" the process other than asking the remote transmitter to repeat the transmission. The data is not "stored" somewhere like on a disk or something similar, it comes in from the network as you read it.

I recommend you change your application architecture so that it stores the data in an intermediate buffer in case it needs to be read multiple times, for example:

```
let fetchUrl callback url =      
    let req = WebRequest.Create(Uri(url)) 
    req.Method <- "GET"
    use resp = req.GetResponse() 
    use stream = resp.GetResponseStream() 
    let text = new IO.StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd()
    callback (fun () -> new StringReader(text)) url

let myCallbackGetListings (getReader : unit -> TextReader) url (chatMatch : ChatMatch) = 
    let html = getReader().ReadToEnd()
```

In the above code I assume that you do really need a reader for some purpose, but if all you need is just text, you can go even simpler:

```
let fetchUrl callback url =      
    ...
    let text = new IO.StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd()
    callback text url

let myCallbackGetListings text url (chatMatch : ChatMatch) = 
    let html = text
```